No pipe found with name 'date' in angular 18
Hi I'm getting a console error when I'm using it in my code that is No pipe found with name 'date' when trying to use it here
<td>{{room.checkinTime | date}}</td>
Error with Pipe
I'm trying to use other pipe, it's same error
Currently, using Angular CLI : 18.0.7
The error was shown:
X [ERROR] NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'. [plugin angular-compiler]

src/app/rooms/rooms.component.html:29:38:
  29 │             <td>{{room.checkoutTime | date: 'short'}}</td>
     ╵                                       ~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component RoomsComponent.
src/app/rooms/rooms.component.ts:9:15:
  9 │   templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


The code you wrote in your post is different from that shown in the error image. Do you still get error when writing date instead of Date? Also please post error message as text into your post instead of just an image. You would like to read How to ask

I'm newbie of Angular, then I tried by myself to put DatePipe in @Component, it works fine.
@Component({
    selector: 'app-rooms',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [NgIf, NgFor, NgClass, NgStyle, DatePipe, CurrencyPipe, 
    LowerCasePipe, DecimalPipe],
    templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
    styleUrl: './rooms.component.scss'
})

Can someone explain why need to add here while I see multiple project hasn't put the Pipe, it has still worked.

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the DatePipe to the list of imports. I think the reason it's not done in some examples is that they are using a separate @Module directive or app.module.ts file, which sets up the app/component/module in a different way.
